# How to Centre align my header image in Underscore_S

Tags: html, css, wordpress, image

I am a student and learning WordPress. I started with the Underscore_s starter theme. For a website I want to centre align the custom header but I am unable to do so. I created a class in CSS named "Headimg" and assigned the class to img in Header.PHP. Which I don't think is the correct way to do it, is it?

Header.PHP

```
<img class="headimg" src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="TCET R&D" >
```

CSS-

```
.headimg{
padding-top: 40px;
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your class to this:

```
.headimg{
padding-top: 40px;
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
}
```